# Удалить / спратять не используемые ячейки в collectionView (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Я использую collectionView внутри tableView для того чтобы в каждой из ячеек tableView можно было скролить изображения. Изображения подгружаю из firebase. Ветка firebase выглядит так:

```
{
  "Дома" : {
    "Дом1" : {
      "address" : "address1",
      "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "name" : "Home1"
    },
    "Дом2" : {
      "address" : "address2",
      "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "image3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "name" : "Home2"
    },
    "Дом3" : {
      "address" : "address3",
      "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "image3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "image4" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "image5" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
      "name" : "Home3"
    }
  }
}
```

И когда я подгружаю изображения то у меня создается максимальное количество изображений, т.е. 5 ячеек в каждом из collectionView. Но на примере дом1 и дом2 у меня остаются пустые ячейки до которых можно скролить. Как мне убрать/удалить/скрыть эти пустые ячейки в дом1 и дом2? Соответственно домов будет около 500 штук, а не 3 дома как я указал в firebase. Я их буду создавать в firebase чтобы они автоматически подгружались в приложение.
Мой код:
ViewController (tableView):

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var nameAddress = [Film]()
var nameAddressRef: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nameAddressRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Дома")

    loadNameAddress()
}

func loadNameAddress() {
    nameAddressRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newImages = [Film]()

        for studioImagesSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            let studioImageObject = Film(snapshot: studioImagesSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
            newImages.append(studioImageObject)
        }
        self.nameAddress = newImages
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return nameAddress.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryRow

    cell.nameLabel.text = nameAddress[indexPath.section].name
    cell.images = [nameAddress[indexPath.section].image1,
                    nameAddress[indexPath.section].image2,
                    nameAddress[indexPath.section].image3,
                    nameAddress[indexPath.section].image4,
                    nameAddress[indexPath.section].image5]
    return cell
}
}
```

CategoryRow (collectionView):

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var images = [String]()

override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.nameLabel.text = nil
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}
}

extension CategoryRow: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.item]))

    return cell
}
}
```

И структура с помощью которой я подгружаю изображения:

```
struct Film {

let ref: DatabaseReference?

var name: String!
var image: String!
var image1: String!
var image2: String!
var image3: String!
var image4: String!
var image5: String!

init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.ref = nil
}
init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    ref = snapshot.ref

    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

    name = snapshotValue["name"] as? String ?? ""
    image = snapshotValue["image"] as? String ?? ""
    image1 = snapshotValue["image1"] as? String ?? ""
    image2 = snapshotValue["image2"] as? String ?? ""
    image3 = snapshotValue["image3"] as? String ?? ""
    image4 = snapshotValue["image4"] as? String ?? ""
    image5 = snapshotValue["image5"] as? String ?? ""
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь:

```
cell.images = [nameAddress[indexPath.section].image1,
                nameAddress[indexPath.section].image2,
                nameAddress[indexPath.section].image3,
                nameAddress[indexPath.section].image4,
                nameAddress[indexPath.section].image5]
```

Вы заполняете массив и его количество всегда равно 5. Вам необходимо либо заполнять массив только если есть ссылка, либо отфильтровать:

```
let imagesArr = [nameAddress[indexPath.section].image1,
                    nameAddress[indexPath.section].image2,
                    nameAddress[indexPath.section].image3,
                    nameAddress[indexPath.section].image4,
                    nameAddress[indexPath.section].image5]
cell.images = imagesArr.filter({ !$0.isEmpty })
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже голову сломал)) Только в моем коде у меня выскакивало пару изменений при вводе предложенного вами кода, у меня получилось так:
cell.images = imageArray.filter({ !($0?.isEmpty)! }) as! [String]